# how to access a specific nested checkbox group

Tags: jquery

Here is a part of a complex form with many checkboxes ...

```
<div class="listbuilder-column">
    <h3 class="con_act_list">Activity</h3>
    <ul id="activity">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="con_act_1" name="con_act[]" class="con_act" value="fabricate"/>
            Fabricate roofs
        <li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="con_act_2" name="con_act[]" class="con_act" value="buy-In"/>
            Buy-in roofs
        <li>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="con_act[]" class="con_act" value="install"/>
            Install roofs
        <li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="listbuilder-column"> ........   more checkboxes </div>
```

I would like to know how to determine the state these checkboxes, ie checked or not. 
I am using `$(.con_act input:checked").length` but the checkboxes are nested within a div ...

Comment: Please don't ask the same question over and over. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make your specific `div` have an ID (i.e. `specdiv`) and your selector should be

```
$("#specdiv [type=checkbox]:checked").length
```

or, since you already have an ID for the `ul`, go for this:

```
$("#activity [type=checkbox]:checked").length
```

Here's a jsfiddle for playing around with possibilities: http://jsfiddle.net/7WnBG/

Comment: that will select selected radio's too, ou might consider adding ':checkbox' filter too.

Answer (score 0):

To find the number of checked checkboxes:

```
$('input.con_act:checkbox:checked').length;
```

This works by first finding the `input` elements, then filtering by the class-name, then selecting only those that are, in fact, of `type="checkbox"` and, finally, selecting only those that are checked at the time that line of jQuery is executed.

The level of nesting is, pretty much, irrelevant, but you can easily search for only those within a specific parent element:

```
$('#activity').find('input.con_act:checkbox:checked').length;
/* or: */
$('#activity input.con_act:checkbox:checked').length;
```

Comment: OP wnats only the ones inside the specific div. OP already asked this question. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10621815/570191

Comment: @Adrian: thanks. I hadn't realised it was quite so obvious (and redundantly) a duplicate.